# OnFocusChangeListener in RadioGroup - Android

Tags: java, android

I need to add onFocusChangedListener to RadioGroup, in order to catch when it looses the focus and perform a validation (e.g. if the user didn't select any radio button in the group).

The radiogroup is between some text fields.

[image: Sample form]

I am logging the focus state for each field while I click in each one and I cannot catch when the RadioGroup looses the focus.

I get this when using "default" RadioButton

```
<RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

E/SAMPLE: input 1 focus true
E/SAMPLE: input 1 focus false
E/SAMPLE: input 2 focus true
E/SAMPLE: input 2 focus false
E/SAMPLE: input 3 focus true
E/SAMPLE: input 3 focus false
E/SAMPLE: input 4 focus true
```

I get this when adding the following on RadioGroup

```
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"

E/SAMPLE: input 1 focus true
E/SAMPLE: input 1 focus false
E/SAMPLE: input 2 focus true
E/SAMPLE: input 2 focus false
E/SAMPLE: input 3 focus true
E/SAMPLE: input 3 focus false
E/SAMPLE: input 4 focus true
```

I get this when adding the following on RadioGroup

```
android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"

E/SAMPLE: input 1 focus true
E/SAMPLE: input 1 focus false
E/SAMPLE: input 2 focus true
E/SAMPLE: input 2 focus false
E/SAMPLE: input 3 focus true
E/SAMPLE: input 3 focus false
E/SAMPLE: input 4 focus true
```

As you can see, I never got the radio button nor radio group focus status.

But If I use the tab key (on my computer keyboard) to change between fields I get this:

```
E/SAMPLE: input 1 focus true
E/SAMPLE: input 1 focus false
E/SAMPLE: input 2 focus true
E/SAMPLE: input 2 focus false
E/SAMPLE: input 3 focus true
E/SAMPLE: input 3 focus false
E/SAMPLE: rb1 focus true
E/SAMPLE: rb1 focus false
E/SAMPLE: rb2 focus true
E/SAMPLE: rb2 focus false
E/SAMPLE: rb3 focus true
E/SAMPLE: rb3 focus false
E/SAMPLE: input 4 focus true
E/SAMPLE: input 4 focus false
```

So, It's possible to catch focus on RadioGroup?

Thanks in advance.

This is the code I am using.

I have a test formulary as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/input1_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Field 1" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/input2_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Field 2" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/input3_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Field 3" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checkedButton="@+id/rb1"
                android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="1" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="2" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="3" />
            </RadioGroup>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/input4_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Field 4" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my test activity:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.OnFocusChange;
import example.com.materialsample.R;

public class FocusActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static Intent getStartIntent(@NonNull Context from) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(from, FocusActivity.class);
        return intent;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_focus);

        ButterKnife.bind(this);
    }

    @OnFocusChange(R.id.input1_text)
    public void onInput1Focus(boolean hasFocus) {
        log("input 1 focus " + hasFocus);
    }

    @OnFocusChange(R.id.input2_text)
    public void onInput2Focus(boolean hasFocus) {
        log("input 2 focus " + hasFocus);
    }

    @OnFocusChange(R.id.input3_text)
    public void onInput3Focus(boolean hasFocus) {
        log("input 3 focus " + hasFocus);
    }

    @OnFocusChange(R.id.input4_text)
    public void onInput4Focus(boolean hasFocus) {
        log("input 4 focus " + hasFocus);
    }

    @OnFocusChange(R.id.radioGroup) // bug in android when group is horizontal
    public void onRadioGroupChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        log("group focus " + hasFocus);
    }

    @OnFocusChange(R.id.rb1)
    public void onRadioFocus1(boolean hasFocus) {
        log("rb1 focus " + hasFocus);
    }

    @OnFocusChange(R.id.rb2)
    public void onRadioFocus2(boolean hasFocus) {
        log("rb2 focus " + hasFocus);
    }

    @OnFocusChange(R.id.rb3)
    public void onRadioFocus3(boolean hasFocus) {
        log("rb3 focus " + hasFocus);
    }

    private void log(String msg) {
        Toast.makeText(FocusActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("SAMPLE", msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure but if you implement OnClickListener or OnCheckChangeListener on each Radio button and inside onClick/OnCheckChange just call radioButton.requestFocus(). It will call onFoucusChange method of previous view

Comment: Thank you @AnkurSamarya that did the trick: @OnCheckedChanged(R.id.rb1)
    public void onCheckedRadio1() {
        radioGroup.requestFocus();
    }

Comment: I think I confused a bit the question, There should be a way to know if the user skips the radio group (selects nothing) and goes to any other field. Is there a way to know that?

Comment: Actually I have also faced this issue but could not get any solution :(